# Laravel: saving multiple models at once / json nested input

Tags: json, validation, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I am submitting a POST request to my API endpoint using Postman.

In my nested JSON, an artist has one or more albums and each album has one or more songs.

I have two questions:
1) How do I perform nested array validation in Laravel? I am looking for an optimal / standard Laravel way to do so.

2) How do I save multiple models together? 
Note: I did create the relationships in my Eloquent models, such as

```
class Artist extends Eloquent {
    public function albums()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Album');
    }
}

class Album extends Eloquent {
    public function songs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Song');
    }
 }

class Song extends Eloquent {
    public function album()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Album');
    }
 }

class Album extends Eloquent {
    public function artist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Artist');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use the validator's `each` method:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [...rules...]);

$validator->each('albums', [...rules...]);
```

---

2) After creating the artist, loop through your `albums` and call `create` on the relationship:

```
$artist = Artist::create(Input::all());

foreach (Input::get('albums') as $album)
{
    $artist->albums()->create($album);
}
```